# awk not printing output

Tags: bash, grep

[image: I am getting this output]

```
grep -hnr '$pattern' /path/of/file/ | awk -F '=' 'BEGIN { print "<table border='1'><tr>" } { print "<td>" $3 "</td>" } { print "</tr>" }'`;
```

the above code is not printing anything when awk command is added to it.
Here I'm trying to convert the file data into table format using awk command.

**Example of data in the files:**

```
name==ABC
City==Rohini
State==Delhi
Age==18
Country==India
```

**Expected output:**

```html
<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
<tr><td>Rohini</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delhi</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>India</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Currently the Output I am getting

```
<table border=1>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ grep -hnr '$pattern' /path/of/file/ | sed -e 's~.*=\(.*\)~<tr><td>\1</td></tr>~;1i\<html><table border="1">' -e '$a\</table>\n</html>'
<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
<tr><td>Rohini</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delhi</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>India</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

You can also use the command directly from a file instead.

```
$ vi sed.script
s~.*=\(.*\)~<tr><td>\1</td></tr>~
1i\<html><table border="1">
$a\</table>\n</html>
```

To use, call the script with the `-f` flag

```
$ grep -hnr '$pattern' /path/of/file/ | sed -f sed.script
<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
<tr><td>Rohini</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delhi</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>India</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but i am getting this error....```sed: -e expression #2, char 1: unknown command: `<'```

Comment: @aastha What version of `sed` are you using? It may be an idea to call a seperate sed script instead. I will add a usage example

Comment: sed (GNU)4.2.2 version

Comment: in sed.script do we have to add something at the start of the script? like in .sh file we have to add #!bin/bash

Comment: @aastha It should not be needed and the script will work as is when called by sed.

Comment: Hi is it possible to get the output like this? `<html><table border="1">
<tr><td>ABC</td>
<td>Rohini</td>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>India</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DEF</td>
<td>Dwarka</td>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>India</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GHI</td>
<td>CP</td>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>India</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </html>`

Comment: there are multiple text files on the same path in the same format like shown in the above question ```name==ABC
City==Rohini
State==Delhi
Age==18
Country==India```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245589/discussion-between-aastha-and-hatless).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` with delimiter `==`:

```bash
grep -hnr "$pattern" /path/of/file/ |
awk -F '==' '
BEGIN { print "<html><table border='1'><tr>" }
{ print "<tr><td>" $2 "</td></tr>" }
END { print "</table>\n</html>" }'

<html><table border=1><tr>
<tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
<tr><td>Rohini</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delhi</td></tr>
<tr><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>India</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: ```awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { print "<html><table border=1><tr>" } { print "<tr><td>"  "</td></tr>" } END { print "</table>
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                             ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { print "<html><table border=1><tr>" } { print "<tr><td>"  "</td></tr>" } END { print "</table>
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                             ^ syntax error```.Getting this error

Comment: [See this working demo](https://ideone.com/El1wlM)

Comment: hey I have added a output snipped in the question..can you pls see to it thanks

Comment: Your expected output is what I have shown in my answer and in the linked demo

Comment: yes but I am getting output as shown in the above image .

Comment: awk is not reading $2..it works fine on the terminal but not in the cgi script

Comment: I have already provided a working demo. If you can reproduce your error on a new ideone demo then I can investigate otherwise you need to debug your script yourself.